# Matlab's nanmean( ) function not working with dimensions other than 1

Tags: function, matlab

Take this example from the [mathworks help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/nanmean.html) of `nanmean()`:

```
 X = magic(3);
X([1 6:9]) = repmat(NaN,1,5)

X =

   NaN     1   NaN
     3     5   NaN
     4   NaN   NaN

>> y = nanmean(X,2)
??? Error using ==> nanmean
Too many input arguments.
```

Why is it showing error even when the docs say the mean can be taken in any dimension `dim` of `X` as `y = nanmean(X,dim)`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run exactly the code you have and I get no error.  In particlar here is what I ran:

```
>> X = magic(3);
X([1 6:9]) = repmat(NaN,1,5)

X =

   NaN     1   NaN
     3     5   NaN
     4   NaN   NaN

>> y = nanmean(X,2)

y =

     1
     4
     4


>> which nanmean
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\stats\stats\nanmean.m
```

The only thing I can think of is that you have a different version of `nanmean.m` on your path.  Try a `which nanmean` and see if it points into the stats toolbox.

Comment: It points to a different custom toolbox: `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\mgstat\nanmean.m`. How to change that?

Comment: put `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\stats\stats` higher in your path than ...\mgsstat is, in fact just take ...\msgstat out of your path.  It doesn't seem to be a "regular" matlab toolbox, at least its not in my distribution.  Use `editpath` to change matlab's path.

Comment: I just copied `nanmean.m` and copied into my current folder. I do not have permission to make changes in the path because of administrative rights :(. Thanks for your answer btw.

Answer (score 1):

here is the reason:

If X contains a vector of all NaN values along some dimension, the vector is empty once the NaN values are removed, so the sum of the remaining elements is 0. Since the mean involves division by 0, its value is NaN. The output NaN is not a mean of NaN values.

Look at:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/nanmean.html

Comment: I read this statement on the help page. However, this is not the reason because even if you take a matrix without `NaN` like `X=magic(3)` and find its `nanmean`, you would still get the above error: `>> y = nanmean(X,2)
??? Error using ==> nanmean
Too many input arguments.`

Comment: Actually that's not true. I just tried nanmean(magic(3),2) and it worked. what is your MATLAB version?

Comment: what is youe matlab version? I tried on R2009b and it is fine.

Comment: Did you modified the nanmean function yourself for some reason?

Comment: Thanks for your answer TJ1. I chose mwengler as the answer because he recognized the path issue.